# How do I override id_valid() method of Django admin-created form?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django app for a research project, and came across an issue where I needed to change the way a TabularInline was rendered, which fixed slow loading speeds but removed functionality from the Django Admin form. I believe that I can fix the loss in functionality if I can override how the form is validated. However this is a form that I don't believe to be written, and was created by Django. It's called SourceMaterial_peopleForm, which corresponds to and intermediate table in the database.

I was wondering if it was possible to override the methods of this automatically created form, and if so how would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell the admin to use your form instead.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        .... validation logic ....
```

...

```
class MyInlineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).